# $\sigma(f_i, i \in I)$ ($f_i:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$) where $I$ is uncountable

Tags: measure-theory

$\sigma(f_i, i \in I)$ ($f_i:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$) where $I$ is uncountable contains only sets that can be written as $\{(f_{i_1},f_{i_2},...) \in B\}$ where $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N})$ and $i_1,i_2,...$ is an enumeration of a countable subset of $I$.

Any hint please?

Comment: If $f_i$ is a real-valued function  what is the meaning of your statement that $f_i$ contains sets (of certain kind)?

Comment: @PVanchinathan: He (or she) is talking about the sigma algebra generated by the $f_i$. Notice the "$\sigma$" before the "$f_i:i\in I$"

Comment: Thanks Shalop. I see there is an edit that improves clarity. But still I don't understand  the meaning of $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots)\in B\}$. Of course this area of mathematics is unfamiliar territory to me. So I could be ignorant of conventions that are akin  to summation conventions used by Physicists.

Comment: Thanks Shalop  for taking the trouble. Even when I can't answer questions I sometimes read questions/answers  just to to see if I can learn something from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically asking whether any set in the sigma algebra generated by uncountably many functions will "only depend on countably many of these functions."

Let me first rephrase your question using more abstract but also very convenient notation.

Formally, your question can be rephrased as follows: Let $\;f: \Omega \to \Bbb R^I$ denote the product map $\omega \mapsto (f_i(\omega))_{i\in I}$. For subsets $A \subset I$, let $\pi_A: \Bbb R^I \to \Bbb R^A$ denote the canonical projection map $g \mapsto g|_A$. Then for any set $D \in \sigma(f_i:i \in I)$, is it possible to find a countable subset $A \subset I$ such that $D = (\pi_A \circ f)^{-1}(B)$ for some $B \in \mathcal B(\Bbb R^{A})$ ?

The answer to your question is "yes."

Here is a sketch of the proof.

Let $\Sigma$ denote the collection of all subsets of $\Omega$ which are of the form $(\pi_A \circ f)^{-1}(B)$ for some countable set $A \subset I$ and some $B \in \mathcal B(\Bbb R^A)$. Then $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Let's prove this. To prove that $\Sigma$ is closed under complements, note that $$\big[ (\pi_A \circ f)^{-1}(B) \big]^c = (\pi_A \circ f)^{-1}(B^c)$$

To prove that $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions, suppose $\{E_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \subset \Sigma$. For each $n$, let's say $E_n = (\pi_{A_n} \circ f)^{-1}(B_n)$. Let $A = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n$. For $n \in \Bbb N$, let $p_n: \Bbb R^A \to \Bbb R^{A_n}$ denote the projection $g \mapsto g|_{A_n}$. Then we can write $\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}E_n = (\pi_A \circ f)^{-1}(B)$, where $B = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} p_n^{-1}(B_n)$. This shows that $\Sigma$ is a sigma algebra.

Also, I claim that $\Sigma$ contains the generating set for $\sigma(f_i:i \in I)$ which consists of all sets of the form $f_i^{-1}(B_i)$ for $i \in I$ and $B_i \in \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$. Indeed, for fixed $i \in I$ and $B_i \in \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$, we can write $f_i^{-1}(B_i) = (\pi_A \circ f)^{-1}(B)$ where $A = \{i\}$ and $B = B_i$.

This shows that $\Sigma$ is a sigma-algebra which contains a generating set for $\sigma(f_i:i\in I)$, and thus we conclude that $\Sigma = \sigma(f_i:i\in I)$, which is the desired result.